# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes at boot in VirtualBox 6.1.32

Tags: virtualbox

For a class project, I have to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I have been able to get through the entire setup and installation process just fine. However, when it comes to actually booting up the system, it is infinitely stuck on the [startup screen](https://ibb.co/YypSvrQ). My log can be found on this [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JXdmtCZB).

Edit: I didn't follow any guide or anything. I basically created the VM that you would with any other Virtual Machine, just accepting the default settings with 2 GB RAM and I think 10 GB hard drive. A lot of what I did is visible in the log that I linked above. I never had a problem before today though, so I feel that this may actually be potentially a problem with VirtualBox though, as I now notice that my Windows 7 installation is also broken. I do believe that it did install successfully though, as it said to remove the disk after it installed everything, which I did when it told me to.

Again though, this may be on the part of VirtualBox and not Ubuntu, given that I've had other VMs break. I'll have to contact their support. Thanks for the help so far everyone!

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree with your assessment that the installation was completely successful if you can't get it to boot. Are you following some guide or tutorial? Did you allocate enough resources for Ubuntu? We can't really tell you what you did wrong without knowing all of the details about what you did. I suggest you edit your question with more details.

Comment: Edited with a bit more of a description. I do believe though that this could potentially be a VirtualBox problem though, as it seems that more recently, my other VMs aren't booting anymore either :-(.

Comment: Minimum system requirements for Ubuntu Desktop are 4GB of RAM and 25GB of disk space so you didn't allocate enough resources to the container. However if your other VMs are also broken then that sounds like a problem with the host OS not the guests. I'd also strongly encourage you to stop using W7 - it's incredibly unsafe to use. There are many serious unpatched security vulnerabilities that open you up to all sorts of bad things.

Comment: I meant my VM of Windows 7. I run Windows 10 on my host PC. I also have increased it to the requirements and it still won't boot. And yeah, I'm still looking into it. I appreciate it though.